# drools6.3.0.Final spring integration

Tags: spring, drools

I am new to drools and I have got a problem while I am trying to integrate drools with spring following the guide of the drools doc page.Here's the link :http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e13904.

I write some code and a junit test case.**Everything seems go well,the case runs correctly and no exception was thrown.But the rules are not fired**.I am sure that the rule file is ok.
Here is the rule file:

```
package com.huateng.risk;

import com.huateng.risk.fact.ConsumeFact;

global com.huateng.risk.service.NoticeService noticeService;

rule "day consume times limit"
    //day consume times limit 5
    when
        $info : ConsumeFact (dayTimes >= 5 , checked == true);
    then 
        //noticeService.notice("day consume times limit over");
        System.out.println("day consume times limit over");
        $info.setChecked(false);
        update($info);
end

rule "day consume amount limit"
    //3000
    when 
        $info : ConsumeFact (dayAmt >= 3000 , checked == true );
    then 
        //noticeService.notice("day consume amt limit over");
        System.out.println("day consume amt limit over");
        $info.setChecked(false);
        update($info);
end

rule "month consume times limit"
    //day consume times limit 15
    when
        $info : ConsumeFact (monthTimes >= 15 , checked == true );
    then 
        //noticeService.notice("month consume times limit over");
        System.out.println("month consume times limit over");
        $info.setChecked(false);
        update($info);
end

rule "month consume amount limit"
    //3000
    when 
        $info : ConsumeFact (monthAmt >= 8000 , checked == true );
    then 
        //noticeService.notice("month consume amt limit over");
        System.out.println("month consume amt limit over");
        $info.setChecked(false);
        update($info);
end

rule "consume amount limit"
    //2000
    when 
        $info : ConsumeFact (amt >= 2000 , checked == true );
    then 
        //noticeService.notice("consume amt limit over");
        System.out.println("consume amt limit over");
        $info.setChecked(false);
        update($info);
end
```

I have tested this drl file with the code :

```
package com.huateng.risk.demo;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugAgendaEventListener;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

import com.huateng.risk.fact.ConsumeFact;
import com.huateng.risk.service.NoticeServiceImpl;

/**
 * This is a sample file to launch a rule package from a rule source file.
 */
public class RiskHandleMain {

    public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        // KieServices is the factory for all KIE services 
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

        // From the kie services, a container is created from the classpath
        KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();

        execute( kc );
    }

    public static void execute( KieContainer kc ) {
        // From the container, a session is created based on
        // its definition and configuration in the META-INF/kmodule.xml file
        KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("RiskHandleKS");

        // Once the session is created, the application can interact with it
        // In this case it is setting a global as defined in the
        // org/drools/examples/helloworld/HelloWorld.drl file
        ksession.setGlobal( "noticeService", new NoticeServiceImpl() );

        // The application can also setup listeners
        ksession.addEventListener( new DebugAgendaEventListener() );
        ksession.addEventListener( new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener() );

        // To setup a file based audit logger, uncomment the next line
        // KieRuntimeLogger logger = ks.getLoggers().newFileLogger( ksession, "./helloworld" );

        // To setup a ThreadedFileLogger, so that the audit view reflects events whilst debugging,
        // uncomment the next line
        // KieRuntimeLogger logger = ks.getLoggers().newThreadedFileLogger( ksession, "./helloworld", 1000 );

        // The application can insert facts into the session
        final ConsumeFact info = new ConsumeFact();
        info.setAmt(2000L);
        info.setDayTimes(8L);
        info.setDayAmt(2000L);
        info.setMonthTimes(8L);
        info.setMonthAmt(5000L);

        ksession.insert( info );

        // and fire the rules
        ksession.fireAllRules();

        // Remove comment if using logging
        // logger.close();

        // and then dispose the session
        ksession.dispose();
    }

}
```

In my spring integration case, i have two spring bean files:

The first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop    
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- proxy-target-class -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.huateng.risk,org.kie.spring" />

    <import resource="classpath:spring-drools.xml" />
</beans>
```

And the second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd ">

    <kie:kmodule id="riskKmodule">
        <kie:kbase name="riskKbase" packages="com.huateng.risk">
            <kie:ksession name="ksRiskHandle">
                <!-- <kie:fileLogger file="drools" threaded="true"
                    interval="10" /> -->
                <!-- <kie:batch>
                    <kie:set-global identifier="noticeSerivce">
                        <bean class="com.huateng.risk.service.NoticeServiceImpl"/>
                    </kie:set-global>
                </kie:batch> -->
                <!-- <kie:listeners>
                    <kie:ruleRuntimeEventListener
                        ref="org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener" />
                    <kie:agendaEventListener
                        ref="org.kie.api.event.rule.DebugAgendaEventListener" />
                    <kie:processEventListener
                        ref="org.drools.core.event.DebugProcessEventListener" />
                </kie:listeners> -->
            </kie:ksession>
        </kie:kbase>
    </kie:kmodule>

</beans>
```

In the second file, the kbase configurs the resources package which exactly stores the drl files.

I have got two questions:

1 As I wrote before, my test case runs normally with no exceptions,but the rules are not fired.And when i debug my code,i find the something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
package com.huateng.risk;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.cdi.KBase;
import org.kie.api.cdi.KSession;
import org.kie.api.definition.KiePackage;
import org.kie.api.definition.rule.Rule;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.AgendaEventListener;
import org.kie.api.runtime.Environment;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.huateng.risk.fact.ConsumeFact;
import com.huateng.risk.service.NoticeService;

@Component("riskHandle")
public class RiskHandle {
    @Autowired
    private NoticeService noticeService;
    @KSession("ksRiskHandle")
    private KieSession ksession;
    public void execute(ConsumeFact info ) {
        try{
            ksession.insert( info );
            Environment env = ksession.getEnvironment();
            KieBase kbase = ksession.getKieBase();
            Collection<KiePackage> packages = kbase.getKiePackages();
            KiePackage pkg = kbase.getKiePackage("com.huateng.risk");
            Rule rule = kbase.getRule("com.huateng.risk", "day consume times limit");
            ksession.fireAllRules();
            ksession.dispose();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setNoticeService(NoticeService noticeService) {
        this.noticeService = noticeService;
    }

    public void setKsession(KieSession ksession) {
        this.ksession = ksession;
    }

}
```

When I was debugging my code, i found the "packages" was empty array.So was the "pkg" and the "rule".**It seems that the kbase did not loaded the resources stored in the sub-folder "/com/huateng/risk" under the "src/main/resources" which is defined as a source folder by maven default**.

So **Have i done wrong somewhere with spring integration**?

2  I am trying to set globals to do some bussiness stuff.Let's back forward to the second spring bean file.When i uncommented the set-globals config ,i got an exception : **Unexpected globals**.

**How to configure the globals with spring integration** ?

Here is the set-globals config in the second spring bean file:

```
<kie:batch>
                    <kie:set-global identifier="noticeSerivce">
                        <bean class="com.huateng.risk.service.NoticeServiceImpl"/>
                    </kie:set-global>
                </kie:batch>
```

Comment: noticeSerivce vs noticeService?

Comment: Unless the constructor of `ConsumeFact` sets `checked = true`, no rule will fire.

Comment: @laune Thanks for your answers! But it still can not solve the problems.

Comment: @laune Thanks for your answers! But it still can not solve the problems.I have modified the "noticeSerivce " to  "noticeService" (first all ,this is a stupid fault) and still got the Unexpected Globals. And the ConsumeFact ,the checked is set to true by default.In fact , i have tested the drl file with the ConsumeFact as i mentioned above.

Comment: If you see an error message "unexpected global [noticeService]" in spite of the name in the setGlobal statement being the same as the one in the DRL file you'll have to assume that no rule base has been loaded (or one not containing the DRL you think). Seeing an empty package collection confirms that. - Sorry, I'm not able to help you with your Spring fall.

Comment: @laune thank you all the same!You are right. There is no rule base was loaded .But just can not find out why.Maybe i should read more documents about the drools6.x.This is the first question i have posted on stackoverflow and you are the first one answering.Great thanks for you.

Comment: Added the [tag:spring] tag.